# Embedding XSL Stylesheet into XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt, servlets, stylesheet

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.fakedomain.com/sally.xsl"?>
```

And the following content in sally.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:for-each select="documentcollection/document">
<p>
<xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
<xsl:value-of select="title"/><br />
<xsl:value-of select="description"/><br />
<xsl:value-of select="link"/><br />
</xsl:for-each>
</p>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the browser displays the XML as though the XSL line is not present. Do you know why the browser is ignoring the XSL stylesheet? Is the style sheet wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I have the following XML:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.fakedomain.com/sally.xsl"?>
> ```

This isn't a well-formed XML document (no top element present), so it isn't much of a surprize the browser doesn't treat it as such.

**Solution**:

Update your "XML" to a really well-formed XML document, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///c:/temp/delete/xxx.xsl"?>
<t/>
```

**With this stylesheet in `c:\temp\delete\xxx.xsl`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     XXX
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when the XML file is opened with IE, the browser displays the result of the transformation**:

XXX

Comment: Hi, turns out my problem was that I put hte xsl file in the wrong directory in tomcat. I did have a top element, the documentcollection element. But I like the use of  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>. And I think setting the method attribute of output to html lets the browser know i am converting the xml to html.
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>, which I added to my xsl file as well.

Comment: @user700996: You are welcome. I am glad you found out what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your not closing off one of your for-each tags?

Answer (score 0):

the `xsl:for-each` loop of `select="rss/channel/item"` is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

It could be [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) security restrictions. If your XML and XSLT are not hosted in the same location, then the browser may be refusing to fetch the XSLT and apply it to your XML file.

Comment: Hi, the same origin policy seems to make sense. However, I am generating the xml dynamically from a servlet. Therefore there is no xml "file", only an xslt file. I am wondering should I put the xslt file in the same directory as the java files for my servlet, or as the compiled class files? Where is a suitable place to put the xsl file?

Comment: Hi, actually I figured out the problem. The problem has nothing to do with my xml or xsl. It turns out, in my servlet, I accidentally set the content-type to text/html instead of text/xml

Comment: Hi, even though it's now reading in the xsl, it gives me the following error: Error loading stylesheet: An unknown error has occurred (805303f4). I googled around and decide to use a relative path instead. But then I got this error: Error loading stylesheet: A network error occured loading an XSLT stylesheet:. Any idea what's happening? Thanks.